# Railway Prisma Generate failing to install Prisma CLI in nixpack

Tags: python, node.js, prisma, nix, railway

I am stuck trying to deploy a FastAPI backend on [railway](https://railway.app) because prisma fails to install its CLI during the build process. It was working just fine the last time I deployed it.

```
#12 [ 8/10] RUN  prisma generate

 

#12 0.675 Installing Prisma CLI

 

#12 1.036  * Install prebuilt node (20.8.0) .

.

..

. done.

 

#12 5.651 An error ocurred while installing the Prisma CLI; npm install log: node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.36' not found (required by /nix/store/xpxln7rqi3pq4m0xpnawhxb2gs0mn1s0-gcc-12.3.0-lib/lib/libstdc++.so.6)

#12 5.651

#12 5.652 Traceback (most recent call last):

#12 5.652   File "/opt/venv/bin/prisma", line 8, in <module>

#12 5.652     sys.exit(main())

#12 5.652   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prisma/cli/cli.py", line 39, in main

#12 5.652     sys.exit(prisma.run(args[1:]))

#12 5.652   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prisma/cli/prisma.py", line 36, in run

#12 5.652     entrypoint = ensure_cached().entrypoint
```

I can see that it is failing due to `GLIBC` and probably because it is using a pre-built node version. But I can't figure out how to modify any of this build behaviour.

Any ideas are welcome!

I tried setting a few env variables like `NIXPACKS_NODE_VERSION` to 16, 18, 20 and
`NIXPACKS_NO_CACHE` to `true` but it changed nothing. Seems there is a platform issue with how it processes these builds